# Unique String printing every 5th 10th and last position

Tags: c++, arrays, string, if-statement

Been stumped for a good day now on this one, I know I just need the "=" sign and ">" end piece to the question.Any hints or advice>?

```
 int main()
 {
   //Calling in Variables
   int data;
   int counter;

   //Step 1:Prompt the user to pass in a positive integer between (0-50)
   cout << "Type in a number between 0-50 to plot your bar:  " << endl;
   cin >> data;

   //Step 2: Error check for bad numbers that have been input.
   if(data < 0) {
     cout<< "ERROR: " << data << " is not in acceptable range."<< endl;
   }

   //Step 3: 
   if(data >= 0 && data <= 50){     
    for(int counter =1; counter <= data; counter++) {
     if(counter % 10 !=0) 
      cout<< "|";

     else(data%5 == 0) 
      cout << "+";

   }



  }
   else
     cout << "BarPlot - End Plot by User Request"

   return (0);
}
```

Create a simple Bar Graph Plotter (BarPlot) that takes in a positive integer number between [0 50], and plots the
number as a simple bar. The program should only accept data within this range. Any negative value input should
terminate the Program. Any input larger than 50 should result in an error message and a prompt to enter another
number.

Example Output:

BarPlot – A Simple Bar Graph Plotter:

Input a number in range [0 50] or a negative number to terminate:

---

| Enter Number: 8

| ====+==> 8

| Enter Number: 15

| ====+====|====> 15

| Enter Number: 50

| ====+====|====+====|====+====|====+====|====+====> 50

| Enter Number: 65

| ERROR: 65 is not in acceptable range.

| Enter Number: 0

| 0

| Enter Number: 1

| > 1

| Enter Number: 5

| ====> 50

| Enter Number: -1

---

BarPlot – End Plot by User Request

Comment: You already asked this a little while ago and then you removed it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986810/printing-a-string-in-c-with-every-5th-and-10th-and-last-symbol-unique What are you actually asking?

Comment: The other one sucked so I made a new one with revised edits.

Comment: If all your asking is how to put a `>` on the end then just print it at the end of your for loop?

Comment: I have added an answer but i think this question will still be closed unless you make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a really simple question that you have made complex by putting it in a big lump of text. You have pretty simple logic, you want to print out `=` except for every 5th and 10th number. You were basiclly already there:

```
for(int counter =1; counter <= data; counter++) {
    if(counter % 10 ==0) 
       cout<< "|";
    else if(counter%5 == 0) 
       cout << "+";
    else
       cout << "=";
}
cout << ">" << yournumberthing << endl;
```

You just needed to think about it some more.

Comment: Wow I cant believe I didn't think of that...I need to start thinking harder or simpler i guess!

Comment: @user3698026 Hope that helps, tbh though, you really should be doing homework yourself rather than asking here. Otherwise you wont learn anything.

Comment: This is for my own studies...not an assignment of any sorts. I do understand what you are saying though.

Comment: @user3698026 Anyway i think we are done here. Mark the answer correct if it answered your question.